# Torch / Lua, how to get and save parameters of a trained neural network model to file?

Tags: parameters, save, torch

```
th> net
nn.Sequential {
  [input -> (1) -> (2) -> (3) -> (4) -> (5) -> (6) -> (7) -> (8) -> (9) -> (10) -> (11) -> (12) -> (13) -> (14) -> output]
  (1): nn.VolumetricFullConvolution(200 -> 512, 4x4x4)
  (2): nn.VolumetricBatchNormalization (5D) (512)
  (3): nn.ReLU
  (4): nn.VolumetricFullConvolution(512 -> 256, 4x4x4, 2,2,2, 1,1,1)
  (5): nn.VolumetricBatchNormalization (5D) (256)
  (6): nn.ReLU
  (7): nn.VolumetricFullConvolution(256 -> 128, 4x4x4, 2,2,2, 1,1,1)
  (8): nn.VolumetricBatchNormalization (5D) (128)
  (9): nn.ReLU
  (10): nn.VolumetricFullConvolution(128 -> 64, 4x4x4, 2,2,2, 1,1,1)
  (11): nn.VolumetricBatchNormalization (5D) (64)
  (12): nn.ReLU
  (13): nn.VolumetricFullConvolution(64 -> 1, 4x4x4, 2,2,2, 1,1,1)
  (14): nn.Sigmoid
}
```

I want to get and save parameters of this model to file.
I tried net:getParameters(). But I get a one-dimensional array.
How can I get and save parameters of this model to file?

Answer (score 1):

You can save by `torcy.save('mynet.t7',net`.
Parameters can be accessed by 
`params, grad_params = net:getParameters()`. After obtaining this variable, you can save it using torch.save which saves objects using binary format. So you save any variable in torch this way

Comment: Probably worth making this answer more complete by explaining how to reconstruct the net from the saved binary.